# Fonts are displaced when using Google Apps Script to export a Google Doc to PDF

Tags: google-apps-script

I used Google App Script and encountered a problem. There is a Google doc file, and I want to export it to PDF. So I used the `.getAs('application/pdf')`. The generating of PDF works, but the fonts are displaced.

(The original fonts is "標楷體", and exported PDF's fonts is default fonts. )

The code:

```
let doc = DocumentApp.openById(newDocId);
let pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(newDocId).getAs('application/pdf');
```

I searching for the solution. I found that using Google Doc exporting will cause same problem. But using print to save to PDF make the fonts correct. However, I cannot find any print relation function in Google Apps Script.